# Where is dtx-highlight-item CSS coming from?

Tags: html, browser

I have 2 jQuery powered web games where users can click on numbers or letters which are then added to another div. Code looks like this:

```
$('.number').mousedown(function() {
    var nr = $(this).html();
    formula[formula.length] = nr;
});
```

For 99% of users everything works fine, however some report that strange HTML is inserted into div. For example, when code tries to insert letter W, the following gets added to the div:

```
<span id="dtx-highlight-item">W</span>
```

I guess I could use .text() instead of .html(), I'm changing that now, but I'd like to know where is dtx-highlight-item coming from? I don't place it in my code, so I guess it's some Firefox extension or something like that.

Comment: BTW, googling for dtx-highlight-item shows a lot of hits, so this seems to be wide-spread issue.

Comment: Look at this page for example, it highlights the letter "i" in word "Childhood" with yellow color: http://www.shroomery.org/forums/showflat.php/Number/14768043.

Comment: I also noticed that. Until now my guesses are: malware toolbar searchqu (has files dtx.ini, dtx.css) which may highlight words or some extension as you wrote.

Comment: I retagged as it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it comes from this company: http://dynamictoolbar.com/. It's basically adware that lets non-developers build browser toolbars. Because it won't have the Dynamic Toolbar branding, it won't be obvious which one is adding the classes.